# The difference between flush() and ob_flush() in PHP

Tags: php

I have a doubt between these two functions.
According to my understanding，there are four buffers when we use PHP via web. PHP buffer,SAPI(FAST-CGI) buffer,nginx buffer and exploer buffer. So could anyone tell me how these buffers work and where flush() and ob_flush() are supposed to be used?

Comment: flush() is more internal to php where as ob_flush() which is more userspace/your application layer.